# Reduce mysql query ( Fulltext-search ) execution runtime, server-side?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, django

****VPS**:**

- ubuntu
- Django (latest)
- Python3.6
- Mysql

**Structure :**

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `wallpaper` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `tags` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `downloads` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wallpaper_preview` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wall_height` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wall_size` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `wall_width` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `tags` (`tags`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14566 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Code ( from django views.py ):**

```
posts = mytable.objects.raw('SELECT id,
    MATCH (tags) AGAINST (\''+some.tags+'\') as score
    FROM table ORDER BY score desc;')
```

**Excution Time (5 runs in sec, views.py):**

```
6.103515625e-05
6.4849853515625e-05
6.318092346191406e-05
8.034706115722656e-05
8.273124694824219e-05
```

**Runtime checked using:**

```
start = time.time()
posts = modelname.objects.raw('SELECT id,
    MATCH (tags) AGAINST (\''+some.tags+'\') as score
    FROM table ORDER BY score desc;')
end = time.time()
print(f"Runtime views is {end - start}")
```

**Tried raw from ssh, mysql command line**

```
SELECT id, MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('car') as score
    FROM tablename ORDER BY score desc;
```

**result:**

```
11834 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

**Indexed using:**

```
ALTER TABLE 'tablename' ADD FULLTEXT('tags');
```

is there a better way. or something with Django ORM.

**example search:**

*'superscars'* searched in *'road,hometown,supercar,extremecars'*

if mysql is performing in 0.09 sec then why django takes so much time
, or i have done something wrong or missed something.
*i have asked this on stackoverflow, they redirected me here*

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Can I get the table structure ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI u mean, `mysqldump -u root -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql` or `DESCRIBE yourDatabasename.yourTableName;`, also, i have updated the question, do check the structure

Comment: Was the Query cache enabled?  That's about the only way to get a time of 0.06ms.  How many rows in the resultset?  Perhaps 14K?